# Как переделать google maps zoom в MKCoordinateSpan?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps-api

Есть от гугла: *latitude, longitude* и *zoom* (`int`|`float`), надо сделать карту `MapKit`. Координаты поставил и вроде работает, а вот с *zoom* проблемы, так как `MapKit` работает с

```
MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees, longitudeDelta: CLLocationDegrees)
```

где `CLLocationDegrees` - `Double`. Как перевести *zoom*(`float`|`int`) в `MKCoordinateSpan`?

Comment: зум, который у вас есть передать в оба значения - и lat и lon

Comment: К сожалению не так просто, zoom у гугла от 1 до 20, а у mapkit 0 до 100 причем не понятно как происходит расчет, все еще в Double цифры получаются странные, пока по расчетам близко http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/ но когда вертишь телефон все ломается. Плюс погрешность приличная